# docker-compose & Dockerfile: ADD failed: no source files were specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Angular project including a Dockerfile at root folder.

```
FROM nginx:1.15.5

#RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get install -y nano

# Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

#Copy sources into docker
ADD dist/privilege/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

# ADD cert/* /etc/nginx/
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/cert 

ADD .cert/my-site.com.crt /etc/nginx/cert/my-site.com.crt
ADD .cert/my-site.com.key /etc/nginx/cert/my-site.com.key

RUN mkdir -p /var/opt/run/nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/opt/log/nginx

ADD .conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

In another folder, same level than my angular project, I have a docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3.0"

services:
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ../privlink/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks:
            - privlink-network
        

networks:
    privlink-network:
        driver: bridge
```

When I run docker-compose build, the Docker build fires up with an error

```
Step 3/10 : ADD dist/privilege/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: ADD failed: no source files were specified
```

I think this is the traversal between the 2 project folders, but I don't know how to solve it
Next I'll have another project folder for my Node back-end to include to my docker-compose

Thanks

Comment: Please show your directory layout. Relative to the compose file, does `dist/privilege/*` exist?

Comment: No the dist/privilege folder is in the Project1 folder. The compose file is alone (Project1 folder and Compose project folder are at the same level)

Comment: Please show your directory layout in the question. Use the edit link above.

Comment: does it work when you build the dockerfile directly ?
also, i think that in a docker-compose you need to specify the image of the service

Comment: dockercompose-services privlink Should I move the compose in the parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

Is your context (the files you want to add to your nginx image) inside the second folder, the one with docker-compose.yml file? Seems like the context in `build.context:` is pointing to the same folder where the compose.yaml is, but all files for the image are in the first dir (the one with Dockerfile). If that is the case, try change `build.context:` to the dir with the Dockerfile.